# How can i select a file with python?

Tags: python, selenium

[image]

I can do like this on Java, but i can't do on Python

```
StringSelection ss = new StringSelection("C:\\Users\\Mert\\Desktop\\hello.png");
Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard().setContents(ss, null);
Robot robot = new Robot();
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_V);
robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_V);
robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
```

Comment: You could just ask for `raw_input` to the path of the file

Comment: Can i select "C:\Users\Mert\Desktop\12.jpg" this file with python ?

Comment: Yes, you just type `file = '/Users/Mert/Desktop/12.jpg` and get the reference for the file and then you can actually use the file through `shutil` or `os`, but I'm not completely sure about that part. But the user will have to type the whole path.

Answer (score 1):

You can open a file GUI similar to Java using Python's `tkinter`:

```
from Tkinter import Tk
from tkFileDialog import askopenfilename

Tk().withdraw()
filename = askopenfilename()
print(filename)
```

And the Python3 equivalent:

```
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilename
filename = askopenfilename()
```